# AS3 help - External as. file a movieclip with lagging issues

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, movieclip

Could someone help me figure the problem in this game. It begins to lag. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3heopwz4s0stfz4/Spill.zip

Comment: do you have a portion of code you can show without me having to DL a zip file?

Comment: You should give us some indications that you have tried to investigate problem on your own, I doubt many people will answer to "download it and fix" call.

Comment: `Stack overflow error at burger() at at Coin/beginClass()` Do check if your `burger` symbol contains any `Coin` symbols. I don't have access to Adobe Flash CS5 to debug this further.

Answer (score 1):

lagging is due to a runtime error. always check if parent contains this at eFrame Handler.

Here is solution: [Spill3](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77523978/Spill3.zip)

Comment: Then the burger appears at the top-left corner, the character doen't jump and its still lag a bit

Comment: I edited Spill2 check please. to explain too much wrong line. and your character is limit jumping only yellow tunnel or green area.

Comment: How could I get the character to jump? It was able to jump. And the enemy doesn't seem to act right? Thanks so far btw.

Comment: +1 for an attempt to fix bugs. I thought that a tutorial is for self-learning though.

Comment: How could I make the character to jump normally? What happen to the enemy, it supposed to kill the character?

Comment: Your code some spaghetti. I'm now resolving. Check back later. Spill3 available Jump check please. And other bugs occur where other Game stage.

Comment: Any progress bitmapdata.com?